# Concatenate a column with comma separated values with other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two columns and we want second column to be concatenated with 1st column by using hyphen.

```
Col1  Col2
1     2
1,2   4,5
```

**Expected**

```
Col1                    Col2
2-1                     2
4-1,5-1,5-2,5-2         4,5
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  You are storing multiple values in a column and that is really bad.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is your table structures?  See here for how to ask a good question:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Sorry, below is the example by using SQL CREATE TABLE #Test (col1 varchar(50), col2 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('1','2')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES ('1,2','4,5')

SELECT * FROM #Test

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do what you want using:

```
select silly.col1, t.col2
from t cross apply
     (select string_agg(col1 + '-' + col2, ',') as col
      from string_split(col1, ',') s1 cross join
           string_split(col2, ',') s2
     ) silly;
```

However, the need to do this suggests a problem with the data model.  I would recommend focusing efforts on fixing that.  You should have tables that have one value of `col1` and `col2` per row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Ours is a SQL 2012 server and the functions in the query does not exist in current environment. This structure is for one table only to pass for Data Driven Subscription in SSRS.